# How to replace blank "yield" variables in laravel?

Tags: laravel-4

I have a master template which has in it:

```
<meta name="keywords" content="@yield('metakeywords')" />
```

The problem is, in some cases I don't want to specify the value of metakeywords. How can I programatically set specific values if they are null?

Also, I want access to overriding these values before the template is printed to screen because I want to be able to add keywords if the keywords are too few, or add other keywords or description stuff based around other conditions. So really, I need a way to manipulate the variables passed to the theme, just before they are passed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a second argument to the `yield` method as a default, which will be used when you don't specify the section in the view. You can use it like:

```
<meta name="keywords" content="@yield('metakeywords', 'Default value')" />
```

So, when you don't specify the `metakeywords` section in your view, `Default Value` will be used, but if the `metakeywords` section is specified, then it will be used instead. You can also pass variables as the second argument to the yield, if you want.